# "Connection to server lost / Touch to retry" when resuming Youtube video

Tags: youtube

Viewing videos with youtube app works fine except when I close the app and get back to the video later. I see the cursor at the time I left it but I get "Connection to server lost / Touch to retry", the video won't resume and touching actually doesn't seem to retry.

The only option is going back to the main app screen, swipe away the video and opening it again.

This happens both on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 and on a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.2

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue and be able to resume videos again?

Comment: Very annoying indeed!